# Построение графиков в Andriod

Tags: android, android-studio

Делаю мобильный клиент для биржы. Нужно строить графики котировок в реальном времени, а так же рисовать на них фигуры и линии технического анализа.

Хочется услышать свежее мнение  - какая библиотека для этого наиболее подходит.
В обсуждениях 2 годичной давности все хвалят эту **MPAndroidChart**. Актуально?

Comment: в этом году актуально писать бирж**и**, рекомендую и в вашем приложении следовать последним трендам в области финансов, а то финансовые акулы они такие, не взлетит приложение-клиент для биржы

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Android Arsenal вам поможет у них там есть рейтинг:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40?sort=rating